# Packaging Enterprise Beans in WAR Modules

Tags: jakarta-ee, jar, ejb, war, packaging

In the [JavaEE 7 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/packaging002.htm#CHDJABEJ)

The following is mentioned

```
Enterprise beans often provide the business logic of a web application. In these cases,
packaging the enterprise bean within the web application's WAR module simplifies
deployment and application organization. Enterprise beans may be packaged within a
WAR module as Java programming language class files or within a JAR file that is
bundled within the WAR module.
```

Then after a short while

```
JAR files that contain enterprise bean classes packaged within a WAR module are not
considered EJB JAR files, even if the bundled JAR file conforms to the format of an EJB
JAR file. The enterprise beans contained within the JAR file are semantically
equivalent to enterprise beans located in the WAR module's WEB-INF/classes directory,
and the environment namespace of all the enterprise beans are scoped to the WAR module.
```

I can't make it past this part, to understand the example.

How is it possible that

**Enterprise beans may be packaged within a WAR module as Java programming language class files or within a JAR file that is bundled within the WAR module**

yet

**JAR files that contain enterprise bean classes packaged within a WAR module are not considered EJB JAR files, even if the bundled JAR file conforms to the format of an EJB JAR file.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specification is trying to say that EJB annotations will be recognized on classes in `WEB-INF/classes/` or within JARs in `WEB-INF/lib/`, but if you decide to move a pre-existing EJB module JAR into `WEB-INF/lib/`, it will be interpreted as a regular JAR, not as an independent EJB module, which means module-specific deployment descriptors in that JAR will be ignored (e.g., `META-INF/ejb-jar.xml`, `META-INF/validation.xml`, `META-INF/beans.xml`, etc.).  Instead, those descriptors need to be merged together and put into the containing WAR's `WEB-INF/` (e.g., `WEB-INF/ejb-jar.xml`, etc.).

Comment: Let paraphrase, you mean for the `EJB` classes to be managed as `EJB` classes by the server, their deployment descriptor must be located in the WAR's `META-INF` directory and no `EJB` deployment descriptor in a JAR's `META-INF` directory will be considered if that JAR is placed the WAR's lib folder ?
And annotations, which relieve you from having deployment descriptors, will force the server to manage the EJB services whether they are in the `WEB-INF/classes/` directory or packaged in JARs under the `META-INF` directory ?

Comment: Yes (assuming you meant "must be located in the WAR's *WEB-INF* directory").

Comment: @BrettKail if you would provide a link to further documentation on how EJB's are packaged as JAR's that would be appreciated.

Comment: See Chapter 15 of the [EJB 3.2 specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr345/index.html).